# Will the werewolf attack on harmless?

Tags: survivalcraft

I'm new to playing survivalcraft. I want to go on harmless, but I don't know if werewolves will attack me. Will they attack me?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://kaalus.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/game-modes/ animals will attack only if you attack them first.

> Harmless mode exists to cater for the needs of the building folk. It is not completely devoid of danger, but it will be much easier to stay alive there. Animals will not attack unprovoked, fall damage is reduced, health regeneration is very fast, and all digging is speeded up by 25%.